# Header filter does not apply Cache Control : no cache for liferay pages

Tags: filter, liferay, liferay-7

I turned on Header Filter and add settings

```
<filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>Header Filter - No Cache</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
        <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>
        <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
    </filter-mapping>

<filter>
        <filter-name>Header Filter - No Cache</filter-name>
        <filter-class>com.liferay.portal.servlet.filters.header.HeaderFilter</filter-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>url-regex-ignore-pattern</param-name>
            <param-value>(css|gif|svg|ico|jpg|js|png)+(\?.*)?</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>Cache-Control</param-name>
            <param-value>no-cache</param-value>
        </init-param>       
        <init-param>
            <param-name>Expires</param-name>
            <param-value>-1</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>Pragma</param-name>
            <param-value>no-cache</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </filter>
    <filter>
```

But my headers page look like

```
Cache-Control: max-age=315360000, public
Expires: -1
Pragma: no-cache
```

Cache-Control not equal no cache

How to configure a filter so that it correctly puts a header

Comment: as you're tagging liferay-6 *and* liferay-7: Please specify the *exact* version, as well as detailed steps to reproduce: Which URL are you requesting to see those headers on?

Comment: @OlafKock liferay 7, for example for url http://localhost:8080/plans